# Start-Job including custom cmdlet terminates with strange error

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, start-job

I developed some custom [cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet(v=vs.85).aspx) that serve for different importing tasks to a SharePoint system. Currently all those cmdlets are being run in a serial kind in a single PowerShell script. I want to change this so that each cmdlet gets executed in a separate task (job).

The main script starts a new job with `Start-Job` relating to a separate script that contains the call to the cmdlet. The script starts and executes the cmdlet. I also debugged the code of the cmdlet that gets executed. So far so fine.

But after around 15-20 seconds the job just gets terminated with the following error message:

```
There is an error processing data from the background process. Error reported:
Cannot process an element with node type "Text". Only Element and EndElement
node types are supported..
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I can't find any information on how to handle such an error. I just don't know what is the problem here.

Do I have to add further functionalities to my custom cmdlets so they can be handled in a job?

Here are the scripts.

Main:

```
[object]$credentials = Get-Credential -UserName "domain\user" -Message "Log in"

$job = start-job -FilePath "C:\ImportItems.ps1" -Name ImportItems -ArgumentList $credentials
$job | Wait-Job
```

ImportItems:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [object]$credentials
)

Import-Module C:\Migration\MigrationShell.dll
Import-Items -Credential $credentials
```

Comment: That seems to be an error from `Import-Items`.

Comment: I thought the same. When executing the cmdlet without a job everything works fine. When I debug the cmdlet while being executed through the job it works fine also. But like after 20 seconds it just terminates.

Comment: So how did you solve this? Using the answer below with `[Console]::InputEncoding`?

Comment: Sorry I really can't remember how I handled this issue. You have the same problem and the below anwser helped you?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround on uservoice, did the trick for me

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14915283-job-cmdlets-fail-with-utf-8-codepage

```
if (
    [Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and
    [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0
) {
    [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false
}
```

Comment: More information about the problem: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15770#issuecomment-227898569 and why the workaround works: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15770#issuecomment-228225581

Comment: @OhadSchneider: Note that the issue will be fixed in .NET _Core_ 3.0 and therefore in whatever future PowerShell Core version that will be based on it: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32004

Comment: @mklement0 that seems to be Unix specific though? Not sure it would cover all cases, specifically on Windows: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9766

Comment: @mklement0 great stuff, thank you! As the OP, can you re-open the bug though? I fear that comments on closed bugs sometimes don't get much attention (I could be wrong though, probably depends on the repo)...

Comment: Another good point, @OhadSchneider, thanks - I've deleted the comment about fixing the problem on Windows too and have created a new issue instead: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35950